# For 2 PREFIX and following pages different PHP

Tags: php, url, prefix

I would to have for 2 different url prefix and following pages, different php code.

1. like http://www.example.com/**PREFIX1**/--->
   some php code
2. and http://www.example.com/**PREFIX2**/--->
   another php attribute...

How can I do this? What attributes should I assign? Some examples?

Comment: like http://www.example.com/**PREFIX1**/---> /1/2/3/4/etc nav **menuN°1**   ------and-------http://www.example.com/**PREFIX2**/---> /1/2/3/4/etc nav **menuN°2**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
<?php
    $value = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
    if($value == 'PREFIX1'){
        // do something
        // or include PREFIX1.PHP
    }elseif($value == 'PREFIX2'){
        // do something else
        // or include PREFIX2.PHP
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for response, does it valid also for the "sub-url"? Like the following pages after PREFIX 1 and PREFIX 2 or they become default?

Comment: Please elaborate with proper examples. I am not sure I understand your question properly.

This one will work for URLS like the one you gave in your example. If you want to use the same with a query string attached to it you will have to further evaluate those parameters.

Comment: Basically, I would to use different menus for different language url Like for www.example.come/EN/1/2/3/4/5/etc a english nav menu and for Deutch www.example/DE/1/2/3/4/5/etc different nav menu

Comment: Lol.. sorry.. Just meant to say 'Yes' this will work for the case you described.